# How to execute device camera from main form to another form using Aforge direct show in C#?

Tags: c#, camera, directshow

I have a problem in executing the device from main form to another form I use combo box to select the device, after I select the device from main form I click the button that will open another form, this another form has a button start that when I click it, it should start to run the camera without selecting the device anymore because I already did it in main form but I got an exception saying.

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

this is my code for the other form.

```
private void start_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (start.Text == "&Start")
            {
                if (DeviceExist)
                {
                    frmMain cam = new frmMain();
                    videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[cam.comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString); // The exception shows here!
                    videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
                    CloseVideoSource();
                    videoSource.DesiredFrameSize = new Size(160, 120);
                    //videoSource.DesiredFrameRate = 10;
                    videoSource.Start();
                    lblStat.Text = "Device running...";
                    start.Text = "&Stop";
                }
            }
        }
```

What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: please look at the code i add the coment where the exception occur.

Comment: Hi I solve the problem by copying all my codes in camera directshow from main form to the other form, but I have some goals to achieve if you read the comments below I said that the other form should only contain a start button but not the whole function like the combo box and what I did is I just hide the combo box and execute the camera onload very simple solution but effective hahahahaha.

Answer (score 0):

```
frmMain cam = new frmMain();
videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[cam.comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
```

you create a new instance of `frmMain` with  `cam = new frmMain()` and access it with `cam.comboBox1.SelectedIndex` which is by default -1. this causes the error

Comment: yes I should create a new instance and set the `comboBox1` modifiers to public so that I can access it in the other form, but anyway is there another way to do that?

Comment: another way could be to pass it through until you need it

Comment: What do you mean by pass it through? Please be broad and specific.

Comment: Actually what I am working is I have a very small camera in main form so to make it bigger I created a button named Popup that will show another form showing a wider camera view so the logic is I should not copy anymore the combo box and buttons from main form the only thing that must show in another form is a picturebox for camera bitmap execution and start button.

Comment: create a constructor in your forms which you can create an new instance with the value you need (the SelectedIndex). in your main form you create the new form like `SecondForm secondForm = new SecondForm(this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex);`

Comment: I don't get what do you mean but actually i already did that as you can see above that is the secondform and the `cam.comboBox1.SelectedIndex` is an instance of the main form.

Comment: pls post the code where you create the 'other' form. there you need to make the change

Comment: wait how can I call the value from main form if I use the constructor of the second form as what you post `SecondForm secondForm = new SecondForm(this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex);`, remember that the combo box which I select a device is in the main form and not in the second form.

Comment: yes you need to make the change not in this class but in your mainform class. in your secondclass you then get a value wich can be used instead of cam.comboBox1.SelectedIndex

Comment: I have a problem when I try to do what you said the `SecondForm secondForm = new SecondForm(this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex);` has an exception `WindowsFormApplication.second form does not contain a constructor that takes one arguement` it says

Comment: yes in the secondform you now need create the constructor to accept value.

Comment: I let the c# to correct the exception and like what you said it suggest to create a constructor stub but I can't find where the C# put the generated constructor stub.

Comment: hi I just notice in my second form it generates another class with a variable on it maybe it is the generated constructor stub

Comment: Hi I achieve this in other way but thanks for your suggestion anyway.